# Serializable with IEnumerable Property and a List Member

Tags: c#, serializable

Today I found a gem in our codebase...

```
[Serializable]
public class MonsterClass
{
    // Interfaces are good, especially for testing
    public IEnumerable<FooBar> FooBars
    {
        get { return m_FooBars; }

        // rationale = clever linq performance trick/safeguard
        set { m_FooBars = new List(value); }
    }

    // alas ... it is serializable, thus we REQUIRE, it to be a List
    private List<FooBar> m_FooBars;

    //...
    //ton loads of methods, performing tricks on list of FooBar and other types
    //...
}
```

I want to refactor this monsterclass, by removing all the methods performed on 
IEnumerable<FooBar> into a new FooBarList class.

**Question:** Would something of the following, be a safe replacement? While it still can be serialized!

```
[Serializable]
public class FooBarList : List<FooBar>, IEnumerable<FooBar>
{
    public FooBarList(IEnumerable<FooBar> fooBars)
    {
        this = new List<FooBar>(fooBars);
    }

    //move specific methods here
}

[Serializable]
public class MonsterClass
{
    public FooBarList FooBars { get; set; }

    //still monsterclass, but now the FooBars are refactored out
}
```

Or is it a better idea, and take the lazy/chicken way out, by using extension methods?
(sidenote: I am ruling out the option of refactoring this class, by adding a domain model and adapter inbetween both of these, due to performance impact and refactoring time)

Comment: What's the disadvantage of using extension methods here? You should use extension methods if there aren't any disadvantages.

Comment: @TannerSwett it would be illogical, as we have full control of the classes.

Comment: What's illogical about defining an extension method on `IEnumerable<FooBar>`?

Comment: @TannerSwett see MSDN general guidelines on extension methods (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), but I might be considering this option after all, as we are also in a high performance demanding environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, instead of using Composition, the best alternative is by using an extension method on `IEnumerable<FooBar>`

Answer (score 1):

You're not accomplishing anything by using your custom class.  If you don't want this class to abstract away the fact that it needs to store a `List`, rather than an `IEnumerable`, then make the property a `List` and force the caller to transform any non-List `IEnumerable` that they have into a list (given that they'd need to be doing the morale equivalent with your custom list anyway).

At that point it simply becomes a question of whether or not consumers of this class consider it useful to be able to assign an arbitrary non-List `IEnumerable`, without first converting it to a list, or if the complexity of this class isn't worth that to you.